# CAML query retrieving date range in a sharepoint calendar

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint, caml

I am using CAML query to retrieve events in a range of dates.
Currently, it retrieves nothing eventhough there are events in the range of dates

Is there something wrong with my CAML Query? It can retrieve all events when i take away the query line

Here is my code:

```
DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Now.Date; 

DateTime tomorrowDate = todayDate.AddDays(1);
tomorrowDate = tomorrowDate.AddSeconds(-1);

query.Query = "<Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name=\"StartTime\" /><value IncludeTimeValue=\"true\" type=\"DateTime\">" + todayDate + "</value></Geq><leq><FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\"/><Value IncludeTimeValue=\"true\" Type=\"DateTime\">" + tomorrowDate + "</value></leq></And></Where><Query>";
query.ExpandRecurrence = true; 

query.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' />";

SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

foreach (SPListItem listItem in items)
{
    retrievedData.Add(listItem["Title"].ToString());
    retrievedData.Add(listItem["EventDate"].ToString());
    retrievedData.Add(listItem["EndDate"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains elements `value` and `leq` with incorrect casing. The correct casing is `Value` and `Leq` (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521%28v=office.14%29.aspx)). You also use incorrect date format in the query. You must format the date to string using the `SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime` method (see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/414414/SharePoint-2010-Working-with-Dates-in-CAML)). Also use `FALSE/TRUE` instead of `false/true` in `IncludeTimeValue` attribute.